# Variable resetting problem in a list of objects

Tags: c++, list, sdl

Today I was writing some SDL C++ program, with squares called particles. My problem is that, for some reason, variable y in instances of class Particle is always resetting to the value passed into the constructor after incrementing it by 1. I'm storing the objects in a list.
That's a method that's called every frame:

```
void everyFrame(){
   this->y+=1;
   std::cout<<"update y: "<<this->y<<std::endl;
}
```

And this method is also called every frame, after the everyFrame() method:

```
void blit(){
   this->rect.x=this->x*10;
   this->rect.y=this->y*10;
   std::cout<<"blitting y: "<<this->y<<std::endl;
   SDL_BlitSurface(this->image,NULL,screen,&this->rect);
}
```

This is the part of the code, where I'm adding an object/objects to the list:

```
std::list<Particle> particles;
particles.push_back(Particle(2,10,5));
```

And there I'm executing these 2 methods in the main loop:

```
for(Particle x:particles){
   x.everyFrame();
}
for(Particle x:particles){
   x.blit();
}
```

The console output of the program when y 5 is passed into the constructor is just:

```
update y: 6
blitting y: 5
```

looped around.
I also found out that when I'm storing an object in a normal variable, not in a list, then it works. Is there any reason/fix for it not working in a list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These lines:

```
for(Particle x:particles){
   x.everyFrame();
}
```

are **not** modifying the `particles` list.
This is because `Particle x:particles` is creating a copy of each element before calling `x.everyFrame()`.
You need to change it to:

```
for(Particle & x:particles){  // NOTE: added &
   x.everyFrame();
}
```

Taking a refernce to the list element will modify the element in the list.
The same applied to the second loop applying `blit()`.

**A side note:**
Using the `auto` keywoard is usually recomended in this case. You need to keep in mind that `auto` does not include CV qualifiers, and pointerness/referenceness. Therefore you need:

```
for(auto & x:particles){ ... }
```

And if you are traversing a container without modifying the elements, it is rcomended to use:

```
for(auto const & x:particles){ ... }
```